# Philippians 2:12, working out our salvation be in "joy, love, and faith" or "fear, and trembling"?

Tags: philippians

Philippians 2:12 (DRB):

> Wherefore, my dearly beloved, (as you have always obeyed, not as in my presence only, but much more now in my absence,) **with fear and trembling work out your salvation.**

Working out our salvation be in: joy, love and faith. Or be in: fear and trembling?

I mean is salvation by faith or by works?

If salvation is by faith so working out our salvation should be in Love and Joy.

Or maybe there are two different ways of salvation:

- salvation of the godly be through Joy, Love and Faith.
- salvation of the ungodly be through Fear and Trembling.

The Bible indicates that "Fear and Trembling" is for Servants and Slaves, Look Ephesians 6:5 (DRB):

> **Servants**, be obedient to them that are your lords according to the flesh, with fear and trembling, in the simplicity of your heart, as to Christ:

I hope you get my point of view.

Comment: The apostle is writing to 'dearly beloved' who have 'always obeyed' so he is not addressing the ungodly. He is addressing the godly and to them he says 'in fear and trembling'. Your premise appears to be wrong according to the text you quote. The walk of the godly would therefore appear to be one of fear and trembling with regard to carefully walking a path of salvation. No doubt they _also_ experience other things as well, as a result of their godly walk.

Comment: @NigelJ you can post your point of view in an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do the words "fear and trembling" in Philippians 2 refer to?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/15575/what-do-the-words-fear-and-trembling-in-philippians-2-refer-to)

Comment: @curiousdannii my question is different somehow from this question. In my post I suggest two kinds of people: the godly and the ungodly.

Answer (score 3):

I see this same sort of question regarding Philippians 2:12 has been addressed with various answers. What I'm going to do is give the answer first and then back it up with context. But first the Apostle Paul is "NOT" advocating working out your salvation in order to get saved.

What Paul is saying is for the Philippian believers to work out the "deliverance" or the "solution" of your problems with fear and trembling. Starting at vs2, "make my joy complete by being OF THE SAME MIND, maintaining the same love, UNITED in spirit, intent on one purpose." So what was their problem?

Vs3, "Do nothing from selfishness or empty conceit, but with humility of mind let each of you regard one another as more important than himself." Vs4, "DO NOT merely look out for your own personal interest, but ALSO the interest of others."

Paul then goes on to explain that we are to have the same 'ATTITUDE" of Jesus Christ. vs6, "who existing as God did not regard equality with God a thing to be grasped," What did Jesus do instead? Vs7, "but emptied Himself, taking the form of a bond-servant, and being made in the likeness of men."

Vs8, "And being found in appearance as a man, He humbled Himself by becoming obedient to the point of death, even death on a cross." Now to verse 12 which I already explained and notice verse 13-14, "for (or because) it is God who is at work in you to will and to work for His good pleasure. Vs14, "Do all things WITHOUT GRUMBLING OR DISPUTING." Why?

Vs15, "that you may prove yourselves to be blameless and innocent, children of God above reproach in the midst of a crooked and perverse generation, among whom you APPEAR AS LIGHTS IN THE WORLD."

Comment: @salah Was your question addressed to your satisfaction or is there anything else you would like to know?

Answer (score 1):

Salah,

-If I may be so bold as to try and answer your question from a little different perspective, I would like to encourage you to read Galatians 3 for a very clear explanation between a works theology and a faith theology. You will need to read the entire chapter of Galatians 3 for this is the Apostle Paul expounding on what faith is to the Jews who were accustomed to "works" even though it was a wrong assumption by the Jews. Also Ephesians 2:8-9 further defines salvation by faith. Paul, in his letter to the Galatians, was explaining how faith was different from what they had thought was required as Christians coming out of the Mosaic law. I believe Galatians 3 may answer a lot of your questions about the Christian faith being not of works but a religion of faith. Christians cannot "do" anything to warrant God's love. We rely on God's Grace and mercy.

- In point of fact, Christianity is the only religion in the world were we can do nothing to justify ourselves before a Holy God so that we may go to Heaven when we die. IF I may be so bold once again, A Basic doctrine of Christianity is that there is nothing a human (mankind) may do (works) to justify himself before the One True and Holy God, Jehovah. We are so full of sin that even our works are as filthy rags, literally our works (no matter how righteous they may seem on the surface like helping the poor or even giving our own life for someone else's life) are as filthy as (please excuse the illustration but it's an illustration from the Bible) a woman's minstrel pad which is considered very dirty by Old Testament Laws. To touch blood made a person unclean and thus unable to enter the Court of the Temple and worship Jehovah until they performed a ceremonial washing and waited a definite period of time. There were many things which could make you unclean before God, all of which fall under the heading of sin. This sin is what God, in the form of Jesus Christ removes when we place our faith in Jesus to remove our sins and to "cleanse" us from all unrighteousness. This is what will allow us to one day live in heaven and worship in God's Holy presence for all of eternity.
- I am not educated in the languages as you obviously are and as so many of the people on this stackexchange.com are. I am very comfortable with the doctrines of Christianity and with the Bible and with talking about Christ and what He has done for me and can do for you. If you would like to correspond directly about questions of doctrine or a relationship with Jesus Christ, I would be more than happy to respond. I am not the person to ask about Greek, Latin, or Hebrew. I will promise to only respond to your questions and not to email you unless you have asked me a question. I will not inundate you with emails except at your request about a specific question. If you haven't asked me a question, I won't email. It's up to you. **gene.groover.rn.bsn@outlook.com**  I am an American who lives in South Korea with my wife who is Korean.
- You are obviously a very intelligent person who is very well educated and is seeking God. I can promise you that if you Ask, seek, and knock, God will reveal Himself to you. This is a promise from Matthew 7:7. This is just one of the many promises from God. God desires a relationship with you which is why God sent Himself in the form of Jesus Christ to die for our sins. Christianity is a relationship of the heart (love) and not of the mind. You don't become a Christian because of what you know but because you trust (have faith) in God that you need The Savior to remove your sins. I can promise you from my own personal experience that this life of faith in Christ is far more mystical and fantastic, and wonderful than anything you will ever experience in any other religion. Christ said in John 14:6; "I am the way, the truth, and the life, No one comes to the Father but through me." That's a pretty bold claim for a prophet. Christ was stating Himself to be God which He does so many more times in John 14.
- I only check my email every couple of days so please be patient. I do try and put a lot of thought and prayer into my answers so I am slow in responding.

  Blessings