# Why does Paul use the expression "fear and trembling" instead of simply "fear"?

Tags: word-study, paul, authorial-intent, pauline-epistles

On several occasions Paul used the words "Fear & Trembling" (Phil 2:12; 2 Corinthians 7:15; 1 Corinthians 2:3).  This is often explained as reverence/respect, but why use both word when "fear" can convey the same message?  Did Paul have a specific reason for doing this?

Comment: Good question and welcome to Stack Exchange. We are glad you are here.  When you have a chance, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on  how this site is [a little different](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives#803) than other sites around the web. *This is not a comment on the quality of your answer, but rather a standard welcome message.*   I gave your question a light edit to make your question clearer, but feel free to re-edit if I got anything wrong.

Comment: See also: [Is the "Fear and trembling” in Philippians 2 related to the psalms?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/15572) and [What do the words “fear and trembling” in Philippians 2 refer to?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/15575/what-do-the-words-fear-and-trembling-in-philippians-2-refer-to?s=2|2.1036)

Answer (score 1):

This is likely an example of a hendiadys, a figure of speech where two words are used in a place where one would suffice, for the reason of adding emphasis.

It appears to be a common Hebraism and many see the first such example in Genesis 1 where God "created the heavens and the earth" can stand for "created everything."

Not EVERY construction consisting of,  say, two nouns connected with a "and" is a hendiadys, and the decision to identify the figure in a passage has to be made with some thought.